# apiconnect apic command is missing?

Tags: apiconnect

I have windows 7 install, installed 10/14/2016.  I can use the cli.js and execute apic commands successfully. however apic not installed, is there a way to install post apiconenct install?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the APIConnect NPM module to use the apic CLI commands. If you have NPM installed you can run the following command:

```
npm install -g apiconnect
```

If you run into any issues, please see the following documentation:

[Getting Started: APIConnect](https://developer.ibm.com/apiconnect/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `npm install` command might have not completed successfully? I know this is a cop out, but try to reinstall?